# Checking SMB Version

Tags: sharing, smb, protocol

Is there a command like `Get-SmbConnection` in Windows to check what version of smb protocol I'm currently using on my share points?

Answer (score 15):

To see your SMB versions that are being used run the following command on the server:

```
sudo smbstatus
```

Example:

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
PID     Username      Group         Machine            Protocol Version       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11898     nobody        nogroup       10.0.0.100   (ipv4:10.0.0.100:50612) SMB3_02     

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
IPC$         11898   10.0.0.100    Wed Jun 20 21:07:28 2018
storage      11898   10.0.0.100    Wed Jun 20 21:07:28 2018

No locked files
```

As we can see by the above, one of my Linux boxes is connecting using SMB3.0.2 protocol version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `smbstatus` did not show me any versions, but `smbstatus --verbose` showed where Samba config file was located. Then `/etc/smb.conf | grep SMB` listed configured protocol version.